# Blackberry Build Tool

Tags: blackberry, ant, build-automation

Could anyone suggest the best Build Tools for use in the build process when building a blackberry application.

Is it just the creation of an ANT project, does that cope with signing etc?

Is there a better tool out there?  I'd prefer a lightweight Windows solution.

I normally use Automated Build Studio -- it can build ANT and it can also compile Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any serious alternative to [bb-ant-tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: thanks, I had come across their web site on source forge, I'll investigate it some more.  If no more people come back with a suggestion, I'll make you for the best answer, thanks Michael.

Comment: Yep, I'll agree with that - though like most things BlackBerry, I wish there was a more supported RIM version.

Comment: We use it and were able to integrate it easily into TFS (MSBUILD) using VS Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 (formally Teamprise ). http://labs.teamprise.com/build/extensions.html