# Blackberry Build Creation Without Using BB JDE

Tags: blackberry, build

I am working on a blackberry application and I want to package and sign the blackberry application without using the Blackberry JDE. Is it feasible to do so ?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

The best and easiest is using [bb-ant-tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/). Also please review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942230/blackberry-ant-build-script-for-more-complex-apps) where you'll find build file and it's usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

BB Ant tools actually uses the jde path of the blackberry. Isn't it? I want to package and sign the application without using the blackberry JDE , using specific compilers and signature tool . Please help me. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Correct. It needs path where tools and libraries are located. It doesn't use JDE at all. You could copy rapc, preverify, signtool from bin folder and net_rim_api.jar from lib. And path this path for bb-ant-ttols and it would work.

Comment: @Avinaash, just so we are all clear on terminology, when Eugen says it doesn't need the **JDE**, that's referring to BlackBerry's IDE, the Java Development Environment.  You don't need the JDE to build BlackBerry projects, but you do need *some of* the tools that are distributed by RIM (as Eugen says, `rapc`, `preverify`, `signtool`, etc.)